# Declaring two-dimensional array in HTA (using VBscript)

Tags: arrays, vbscript, declaration, hta

In my HTA script I currently declare a two-dimensional array as follows:

```
Dim wbCell(99, 1)
```

I'd like to also declare the type (String) to see if it speeds up my program. So I try:

```
Dim wbCell(99, 1) As String
```

But the HTA throws an error upon loading, saying *expected end of statement*. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typed Dim's -

```
Dim wbCell(99, 1) As String
```

are legal in other Basic dialects, but not in VBScript. That language is (very) weakly typed (all variables are Variants**), so your aim - speed - isn't attainable in that way. Stay with

```
Dim wbCell(99, 1)
```

** There are sub-types like String or Double and it pays to keep them in mind, but the 'compiler' can't exploit those sub-types to 'generate'/execute sub-type specific code)

Answer (score 2):

VBScript has a single type: Variant. You don't use the `As` keyword. Just assign string values to your array and you'll be fine.